# Dynamically allocating memory for an array of floats

Tags: c++, dynamic-allocation

While trying to understand some code in C++ I came across the following code (and trying to understand its meaning):

```
int SIZE = 256;
float* A = (float *) malloc(SIZE * sizeof(float*));
for (int i=0; i<M*K; i++) { A[i] = 0.0; }
```

I wanted to ask, how is the above different from the following:

```
float* A = (float *) malloc(SIZE * sizeof(float));
```

When I compile the code, both of the versions of "float* A=" compile and execute ok.

Comment: Don't try to write C/C++. They are different languages, and if you pigeon hole yourself into writing code that compiles in both, you'd just makes things harder for yourself.

Comment: On some computers `float` and `float*` happens to both use 32 bits. Then it kind of works.

Comment: @StoryTeller I've corrected it to reflect that it was C++ code. As I have been searching through tutorials / explanations, most of them mention that it is best practice to use new in C++. However I would still like to know a bit more about the difference / similarities between the two.

Comment: No, it is bad practice to use `new` in C++.

Comment: The first reserves space for a bunch of pointers to pointers to floats and the second reserves space for a bunch of pointers to floats. If a pointer to a float and a float happen to be the same size, you get the same space.

Comment: @user118837 *most of them mention that it is best practice to use new in C++* -- The best practice is to use `std::vector<float>`, and forego using `new[]` until you have a darn good reason to use it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thus in order to allocate a memory for an array of floats, the second statement is the correct one, is that right? (as a[b] == *(a + b))

Comment: The first one is heading in the direction of (but not completing) allocation of a 2-d array because it will be a *"column of pointers"* to a bunch of rows of data. The second is a 1-d thing, because it is just a pointer to an area of memory containing individual floats.

Comment: I was going to write an answer and make a pretty diagram, but it is very well explained already here... especially the diagrams. I hope it helps. https://aticleworld.com/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/

Answer (score 1):

> ...I wanted to ask, how is the above different from the following...

`sizeof(float*)` is the size of a pointer to float. On most systems that's whatever number of bytes there are in a pointer, often, but not always, the size of hardware address registers. `sizeof(float)` is the number of bytes in a float, which may or may not be the same size as a pointer.

Comment: What's with the down-vote?  At least have the balls to tell me what you think is wrong with my answer.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but some people believe that `std::vector<float>` is the way to go.

Comment: @BoPersson, yes of course, but not every C++ target is a good candidate for C++ template code.

Comment: @jwdonahue if an implementation lacks `<vector>`, I would categorise it as *not implementing C++*

Comment: Having it available is one thing, having room for template code on the target system is another. I have worked on many embedded systems where the convenience of the C++ language is very nice to have, but the overhead of some of it's more advanced features just won't fit on the device.

Answer (score 0):

`Float*` is pointer. Regardless of what data type a pointer is pointing to, its size is fixed and is 32 bits On 32-bit machine and 64 bit on 64 bit machine.

Comment: Pointer size is up to the compiler implementation, not the hardware it runs on. There are many 32 bit programs running on 64 bit machines.